# How to provide access of special information page to specific users

Tags: python, django, authentication

I am building website using django/python. This website include some webpages (say P1 and p2) in which p2 is form which can be accessed by p1 and link to p1 will be given to specific users via email and messages. I want to prevent other than specific users to go on p1 page of site. consider the situation I have given the link to some user x1 he uses the link and read p1 page and fill form on p2 page now link should expire AND generally URL https://www.website.com/home/p1 should not be directly accessible if entered in browsers for any user. that will prefectly make those pages safe from access of other people. This is quite complex situation how django authentication should be used for it? (Please note that my website does not have single link pointing towards p1 or p2 just the generated link will be way to access p1 and then p2 through p1 can we generate link like that?)

Comment: Could you post the code you already tried? Also, are the users that visit your website logged in?

Answer (score 0):

Why not do something like this in your template?

Based on a user's class boolean, you can show or hide certain things from them when they visit the url.

```
{% if user.is_authenticated and profile != False and user.profile.class1 == True%}

<p>Content which you want to show one class of user. </p>

{% elif user.is_authenticated and profile.class1 == False %}

<p>content which you want to show another class of user</p>

{% else %}

<p><a href="{% url 'login' %}?next={{request.path}}">Log in</a> with your account to view this information.  </p>

{% endif %}
```